# How to get drupal fields and customize themes

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm trying to customize a durpal theme, but I'm getting tired to guess the path of getting different fields of data types. for example, here are some few examples:

```
row.content['#row']._entity.title.value (for titles)
row.content['#row']._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value (for images)
row.content['#row']._entity.field_flag[0].alt (for images alt)
row.content['#row']._entity.body.summary (for summaries)
```

How can I get my taxonomies labels, and is their any effective way to debug and get he nodes & elements structure

Answer (score 0):

Enable devel_kint and print the $content array inside the template file using dump() or kint() to see the array structure of how the field labels and values are saved.

Also Enable twig debugging to see which template is being used and all suggested template names that can be used.

Make the following changes in your services.yml file

```
twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

Clear cache, and inspect the elements in browser to check the template file used and suggested.